# Angular ng If not working with razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

I am using Angular Js with Razor.

```
@{
    var pageMode = (string) ViewBag.PageMode;
}

<div ng-if="@pageMode == 'answer'">
   <h2>Greetings</h2>
</div>
```

Value is in `ViewBag.PageMode` is "answer", still the ng if does not render. i.e "Greetings" message does not work.

What am I doing wrong here... ?

Comment: I'm assuming razor will stop rendering the code at the space? you should probably wrap it in parentheses `@(pageMode == 'answer')`

Comment: @Yasser, why do you need `ng-if` if the decision is made at HTML rendering-time?

Comment: its not quite right that use razor with angular.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cant use `var pageMode` variable inside directives like `ng-if`. you need to use `$scope` variable.

so, simplest thing u can do is,

```
@{
    var pageMode = (string) ViewBag.PageMode;
}

<input type="hidden" ng-model="pageMode" ng-init="pageMode = '@pageMode'">


<div ng-if="pageMode == 'answer'">
```

Comment: There is no javascript in the question.