# Hide div if viewbag is true angular MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewBag in my MVC Controller

```
ViewBag.total = true;
```

and I want to check it in my razor view with angular code and then to display or hide a div

```
<div ng-show="list" class="divList">

       content here

</div>
```

**Update**

```
 <div ng-show="'@(ViewBag.total)'">content</div>
```

I have try this too
[Angular ng If not working with razor syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673786/angular-ng-if-not-working-with-razor-syntax)
but it doesn't work for me. Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: A common mistake is the type conversion.. can you show me code you tried?

Comment: Direct way: `<div ng-show="!{{@ViewBag,total}}" class="divList">`. If you still want to use `list` value, define `$scope.list` on Angular controller and assign `list` with value from `ViewBag.total`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, this  crash my code and the page doesnt't look ok, I don't get any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally dropped the idea of viewbag and solved the problem like that

```
<div ng-hide="myarray[0].myfield == 0 ">Content</div>
```

maybe is useful for someone else

Answer (score 0):

```
    @{
        var total= (string) ViewBag.total;
     }
    <div ng-if="total== 'true'">
    </div>
```

Updated : please Check this

```
@{
            var total= (string) ViewBag.total;
         }
        <div ng-if="total">
        </div>
```

use This

Comment: <div ng-show="'@(ViewBag.total)'">
     </div>

go with this

Comment: same result. It always keeps the div hide even when the viewbag is false

Comment: thank you. I tried it but still keeps the div hide whenever the viewbag is true or false.